# Detection limit for a drop in speed, due to stopping between measurements

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, measurement, bayes-factors

Assume that a device is traveling at a constant expected speed $\mu$, subject to random variation with standard deviation $\sigma$, for a measurement period of duration $t$. Then the expected travel distance will be $\mu t$ over duration $t$.

I am only able to measure the distance that the device has traveled and not its speed. So I must calculate its speed over the measurement period from that distance.

The device occasionally stops for some amount of time between measurements. I want to know if a significant stop occurred during any single measurement period. For simplicity, assume that deceleration and acceleration are instant.

If the device stops for duration $s < t$, then expected travel distance will be $\mu \left(t - s\right)$. Then the expected observed speed for that period will be $\frac{\mu \left(t - s\right)}{t} = \mu - \mu\frac{s}{t}$.

I am interested in stops only above a certain duration $\delta$. So during any given measurement interval of duration $t$, either $s \in [0, \delta)$ (no significant stop occurred) or $s \in \left[\delta, t\right)$ (a significant stop occurred). I am also interested in knowing the smallest stop duration $\delta$ that I can reasonably detect for any combination of $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $t$.

I can estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from past data, and $t$ is a known constant.

**What is a sensible way to proceed in solving this problem?** It seems that any statistically-principled procedure should be unable to distinguish a stop from random variation if the minimum stop duration $\delta$ is small or if $\mu$ is small. But I'm not sure what the right way to proceed would be.

---

At first glance, a likelihood ratio test seems appropriate, with the null hypothesis of $s \in \left[0, \delta\right)$. For example, using a normal distribution truncated at 0, I think I would have the likelihood:

$$
\mathcal {L} \left( s ; \mu, \sigma, y \right) = 
\frac { 1 } { \sigma }
\frac {
  \phi \left( \frac{ y - \left( \mu - \mu \frac{s}{t} \right) }{ \sigma } \right)
} {
1 - \Phi \left( \frac{ 0 - \left(\mu + \mu \frac{s}{t}\right) }{ \sigma }  \right)
}
$$

I'm not good enough to do this in my head, but it looks like it should be possible to get a reasonably tidy closed-form maximum likelihood estimate for $s$.

It also seems like a Bayes factor analysis might be useful here, because I could incorporate additional prior information about whether a stop is probable at any given time, or enrich the model with e.g. negative autocorrelation, without worrying about the models being "nested".

Alternatively, I could attempt to directly compute a posterior distribution for $s$ and set a minimum acceptance probability that it is greater than $\delta$.

Comment: "$\sigma$" is not sufficiently well defined or described unless you are assuming a discontinuous white-noise-like process for the speed, which would be unrealistic in almost any application.  This is a crucial point, because the intended meaning of $\sigma$ will determine the standard deviation of the measured speed as a function of time and that in turn ought to play an important role in detecting stops.  Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @whuber I don't have a good model for how speed varies. I was hoping to fudge it and use something like a white-noise process, because my measurement periods are long enough that the device can make very significant changes in its speed and bearing between measurements. The device in this case is usually a delivery truck of some kind, and measurement intervals could be anywhere from 20 minutes to 2 hours. Looking at my actual data, average speed computed as `distance / time` tends to bounce around very erratically between periods.

Comment: Without a model, and absent any data about durations of stops, it is hard to conceive of any way you could identify stopping at or distinguish it from slowdowns.

Comment: @whuber I am willing accept that a significant slowdown would be indistinguishable from a stop. This system will be used to suggest the possibility of an unobserved stop, which can be investigated further by other systems and/or people, to distinguish it from e.g. getting caught in bumper-to-bumper traffic.

Comment: I have a handful of examples in my data of known stops where the speed is bouncing around between 20 and 60 km/h, and then suddenly drops to 5 km/h for a single measurement period. As a human observer, I would want to flag that period as possibly containing a stop, being consistent with a stop *and* very improbable given the distribution of speeds around that point. So my intuition is that there should be some procedure which would provide usable type 1 and type 2 error rates at least some of the time, as long as the average speed and the amount of variation in speed.

Comment: Also, I should clarify that my minimum stop speed $\delta$ is something I have determined based on business purposes, e.g. I don't care about stops shorter than 10 minutes no matter what. But I expect that I will have to increase the minimum detectable stop speed as the measurement duration increases, as the average speed decreases, and/or as the spread/variation in speed increases.